# T-SQL Query help- find range in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below. I need the result in the range of name as mentioned below. Kindly provide T-SQL query

```
ID  Name
101 AA1
102 AA1
103 AA1
104 AA2
105 AA2
106 AA3
107 AA1
108 AA1
109 AA2
110 AA2
111 AA2
112 AA4
```

Need result as

```
Name Range
AA1  101-103
AA2  104-105
AA3  106
AA1  107-108
AA2  109-111
AA4  112
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select name, min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum_n
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_n);
```

It is a bit hard to explain how this works.  The difference of row numbers is constant for names that have consecutive ids.  If you run the subquery, you'll see what the row numbers look like and how the difference does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use concat with group by as following:

```
SELECT NAME, CONCAT(MIN(id), '-', MAX(id)) range
FROM Table1
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: Good query with faster data retrieval. Missed **AS** key word

Answer (score 0):

Use **with Statement,PARTITION BY and Group By**:

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [ID]) AS Grp
         FROM   @tbl1)
SELECT [Name],
       CAST(MIN(Id) AS VARCHAR(5))+'-'+CAST(MAX(Id) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Range
FROM   T
GROUP  BY [Name],
          Grp
ORDER  BY MIN(ID)
```